# for each row `i` in `A` that matches a row `j` in `B`, assign the index of `j` to a column of `i`

Tags: r

For example, if we have two data frames:

```
A
11  a
11  d  
12  b
13  c

B
13 c
10 b
11 a

->
11 a 3
11 d NA
12 b NA
13 c 1
```

Comment: @akrun crap I changed the example problem at the last minute and forgot to change the example solution.

Comment: It's okay.  Please check the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `paste` the elements in each row for both datasets and use `match` to get the index of the matching strings.  If there are no match, it returns NA.  For example, the 1st row in 'A' i.e. `"11 a"` matches the third row in 'B' `"11 a"` and `match` returns that index.  Assign the output as a new column in "A".

```
A$ind <- match(do.call(paste, A), do.call(paste, B))
A
#  v1 v2 ind
#1 11  a   3
#2 11  d  NA
#3 12  b  NA
#4 13  c   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.table(id = c(11,11,12,13),v = c('a','d','b','c'))

df2 <- data.table(id = c(13,10,11), v = c('c','b','a'))

## merging the two data tables with all values for x retained

merge(df1,df2[,.(id,v,.I)],by=c('id','v'),all.x = T)
##   id v  I
##1: 11 a  3
##2: 11 d NA
##3: 12 b NA
##4: 13 c  1
```